# Why does the order of destruction for data member matter?

Tags: c++

I see in some book that the destruction order of data members in class should be in the reverse order of their construction order. What is the reason of this rule? Any examples are appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this a recommended practice, but a simple statement of fact: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is, in large part, for consistency.  When multiple objects are created in sequence, they are always destroyed in the reverse order.  For example, consider the following example with automatic variables:

```
{ 
    A a;
    B b(a);
}   // b.~B() is called, then
    // a.~A() is called
```

Here, `b` uses `a`.  By guaranteeing objects are destroyed in reverse order of their construction, C++ makes object lifetime management *much* easier.

In a class, you can pass a reference to one data member when you initialize another data member.  Ensuring that objects are destroyed in reverse order, you get the same behavior as with automatic variables:

```
struct S
{
    A a;
    B b;

    S() : a(), b(a) { }
};
```

Note that it's usually not a good idea to have data members referring to each other, but it's both possible and occasionally useful.

Comment: Perhaps it's more accurate to say that when an object B appears after an object A, B can hold a reference to A. The opposite is not true, so destruction in reverse order (B, then A) makes sense, while destroying A first could lead to errors, since B could hold a reference to it.

Comment: @EmeryBerger Yeah, but only because a direct member reference must be initialised on construction. But a reference is not the only form of 'reference': members are free to hold pointers to each other, and those can be set any time, thus being free to be out of order and become invalid. Besides, members may hold 'real' references to each other out of order if said reference is a member of a dynamic container like `std::vector`. So there's not really any 'can' or 'cannot' about this, just _should_ and _should not_. Thinking properly about lifetime is essential regardless of the form of reference

Answer (score 5):

I think maybe you've misunderstood.  It's not that members *should* be destroyed in this order, but that they are *specified* to.

It can be important in rare circumstances to know the order that items are destroyed.

At any rate, that's the order that objects are destroyed in, there's nothing you can do about it but know that it's what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Lifetimes in C++ are nested as much as possible.  It is possible, though usually rare, for data members to depend on each other directly (e.g. pass a pointer of one to another) or indirectly (e.g. both depend on a global, like writing output to stderr), but even when they don't, it's nice to have a specified order, and nesting fits better with how the rest of the language works (e.g. lifetimes at function scope) than other orderings would.

Of course, following the "as-if" rule in the standard, if the compiler/implementation can determine user code cannot observe destruction reordering, then it can do as it likes.